# Отправка сообщение другим пользователям в Телеграм (Библиотека Telegraf)

Tags: telegraf

```js
var fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path"); // Подключаю библиотеку path
var envPath = path.join(__dirname, ".env") // создает переменную envPath, которая содержит путь к файлу .env. __dirname - это глобальная переменная в Node.js, которая представляет путь к текущей директории, в которой находится исполняемый файл.
require("dotenv").config({ path: envPath }) //  загружает содержимое файла .env и помещает его в переменные окружения. Модуль dotenv позволяет загружать переменные окружения из файла .env в процесс Node.js
const { telegramToken, lpTrackerToken } = process.env // Деструктуризация telegramToken и lpTrackerToken изenv файла

const fetch = require('node-fetch'); // Подключаю библиотеку запросов
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf'); // Подключаю библиотеку Telegraf
const bot = new Telegraf(telegramToken); // создает новый экземпляр класса Telegraf и присваивает его переменной bot. В скобках (telegramToken) указывается аргумент, который передается в конструктор класса
var ordersPath = path.join(__dirname, "orders.json")


async function fetchDataAndSaveToFile() {

        const response = await fetch("https://direct.lptracker.ru/lead/103451/list?sort[created_at]=3", { headers: { token: lpTrackerToken } });
        const data = await response.json(); // Преобразование ответа в JSON
        
        if(recivedNewOrder(data.result)) {
            var newIds = findNewOrders(data.result)
            newIds.forEach(newId => console.log(newId))
        }
}

function recivedNewOrder(newOrders) {
    var oldOrders = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ordersPath, "utf-8"))
    return newOrders[0].id != oldOrders[0].id
}

function findNewOrders(newOrders) {
    var newIds = []
    var oldOrders = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ordersPath, "utf-8"))
    var oldOrderIds = oldOrders.map(oldOrder => oldOrder.id)
    var newOrderIds = newOrders.map(newOrder => newOrder.id)
    var newOrderPhone = newOrders.map(newOrder => newOrder.contact?.details?.find(detail => detail.type === 'phone')?.data)
    var adress = newOrders.map(newOrder => newOrder.custom.find(object => object.name == 'Адрес').value)
    var info = newOrders.map(newOrder => newOrder.custom.find(object => object.name == 'Важная информация').value);
    var worker = newOrders.map(newOrder => newOrder.custom.find(object => object.name == 'Исполнитель').value);
    console.log(worker)
    oldOrderIds = oldOrderIds.map(Number)
    firstElemOld = oldOrderIds[0]


    var arrayNewLeads = [];
    var i = 0;

    while (newOrderIds[i] !== firstElemOld) {
        var obj = {
            id: newOrderIds[i],
            phone: '+' + newOrderPhone[i],
            adress: adress[i],
            info: info[i],
            worker: worker[i]
        };
        arrayNewLeads.push(obj);
        i++;
    }


    const chatId = '1013645358';

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayNewLeads.length; i++) {
        let message = JSON.stringify(arrayNewLeads[i]);
        message = message.replace(/^{/, '').replace(/}$/, '');
        let keyboard = {
            inline_keyboard: [
                [{ text: "Отправить фотографию внешнего вида", callback_data: "look" }],
                [{ text: "Отправить чек для оплаты", callback_data: "pay" }]
            ]
        };
      if (worker[i][0] === "Абсолют Новосибирск") {
        bot.telegram.sendMessage(chatId, message, { reply_markup: keyboard });
        }
    }

 

    console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayNewLeads[i]));


    newOrderIds.forEach(newOrderId => {
        if(!oldOrderIds.includes(newOrderId)) newIds.push(newOrderId)
    })
    return newIds
}

setInterval(fetchDataAndSaveToFile, 100000);

fetchDataAndSaveToFile()
```

В переменной `chatID` вписываю свой ID, и мне сообщения отправляет, если запущу бот, но если указываю другой ID, даже в случае того если человек подписан на бот, сообщение не отправляется